# Errors in packages after signing kernel modules

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, kernel-modules

**UPDATE**

Whenever I try to upgrade or install any package no I get the following error

```
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try an upfrade with -f I get the following errors

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Without the -f I get another error

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).



**END UPDATE**

I
```

'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and installed Virtualbox Version 6.1.14 r140239 (Qt5.12.8)

I've tried to create a VM and got the following error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

I then followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560895/sign-kernel-modules) thread trying to sign the kernel modules.

The key was created but wasn't able to sign the modules. (don't remember the exact errors)

But now I got some errors in my packages and I can't solve them.

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.1) but 2.31-0ubuntu9 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm9 linux-headers-5.4.0-26
  linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic
  python3-click python3-colorama
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2.712 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 [2.712 kB]
Fetched 2.712 kB in 6s (460 kB/s)       
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 238445 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another p
rocess: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.1_amd
64.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to purge lib6 but this didn't work either.
What can I do to solve this?

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 accountsservice : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 acl : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed

...

xserver-xorg-video-vmware : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 xwayland : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
 xxd : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
 xz-utils : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 yelp : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 zeitgeist-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 zeitgeist-datahub : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 zenity : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 zip : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to install or upgrade I saw this weird error

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another p
rocess: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I looked up what process blocked it with

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

I've got a lot of permission denies but at the bottom of the list was one identifiable process which I was able to kill. Immediately the MOK configuration screen opened and after rebooting all problems were solved including Virtualbox.

Just to make sure, I've turned off secure boot as it turned out to be a major buzzkill.

Comment: No need to edit the title, just mark this answer as accepted. ))

Comment: thx, at first I wasn't able to post answers on my own post so I put it in my question